# FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegisterApp] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exist"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I make a android app and I'm sending device ID and operator information on my server. Registering is nice is working but when I uninstall app and install app, and if user exist in my database app is stopping.

Error is;

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RegisterApp]
Process: com.example.android, PID: 22570
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "exist"
```

My Register service;

```
public class RegisterApp extends IntentService {

public RegisterApp() {
    super("RegisterApp");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    synchronized (Objects.requireNonNull(intent)) {
        //Register App To Server
        int registerState = Integer.parseInt(DevTools.getPreferences_String(getApplication(), "appPrefs", "reg", "0"));
        String appKey = AppConstant.NOTIF_APP_KEY;
        String baseUrl = AppConstant.NOTIF_BASE_URL + "/register";
        String devModel = DevTools.getDeviceModel();
        String devBrand = DevTools.getDeviceBrand();
        String devId = DevTools.getDeviceID(getApplicationContext());
        String devOs = DevTools.getDeviceSdkVersion();
        String operator = DevTools.getNetworkOperator(getApplicationContext());
        String token = null;

        //looping while fcm token is filled
        while (TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
            token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        }

        if (!token.equals("")) {
            try {
                //check device is registered on server or not
                if (registerState < 1) {
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(baseUrl);
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(7);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devModel", devModel));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devBrand", devBrand));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devId", devId));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devOs", devOs));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appKey", appKey));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("operator", operator));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", token));
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        DevTools.setPreferences_String(getApplicationContext(), "appPrefs", "reg", result);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Error line;

```
int registerState = Integer.parseInt(DevTools.getPreferences_String(getApplication(), "appPrefs", "reg", "0"));
```

How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: what number would you like `exists` to be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uh . I suggest to u use `try catch`
like this

```
try{
 int registerState = 0;
 registerState = Integer.parseInt(DevTools.getPreferences_String(getApplication(), "appPrefs", "reg", "0"));
  }
catch(Exception e){
   }
```

i think this error show your content can't parse to Integer 
repair `Integer.parseInt()` inner codes 
i hope this suggestion helps you